# How to implement Android Bubbles notifications on Android 11(Api 30)+

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-bubbles

I am trying to implement the [Android Bubbles notifications API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/bubbles) but it's not working for me, it's displaying as an ordinary notification. I am testing on emulator API 30(Android 11). I got the [people-example](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/main/People) working on the device, and I am following the [Conversation Notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/conversations#api-notifications) guidelines.

> - The notification uses MessagingStyle.
> - (Only if the app targets Android 11 or higher) The notification is associated with a valid long-lived dynamic or cached sharing shortcut.
>   The notification can set this association by calling setShortcutId()
>   or setShortcutInfo(). If the app targets Android 10 or lower, the
>   notification doesn't have to be associated with a shortcut, as
>   discussed in the fallback options section.
> - The user hasn't demoted the conversation from the conversation section via notification channel settings, at the time of posting.

Please tell me what did I missed?

Also, I got a few optional questions about the design of Bubbles.

- At what point of the app should I create the shortcuts and when to update it?
- How the Person object needs to be cached?

This is what I got so far

```
    Recipient recipient = ...; // Sender data
    Message message = ...;     // Message data

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.CONVERSATION_ID, message.conversationId);

    PendingIntent bubbleIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

    IconCompat icon = loadIcon(recipient);
    Person person = loadPerson(recipient, icon);

    NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle style = getMessagingStyle(person);

    createOrVerifyChannel();

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(getNewMessagesCount(message) + " new messages with " + person.getName())
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setContentText(message.text)
            .setBubbleMetadata(
                    new NotificationCompat.BubbleMetadata.Builder()
                            .setDesiredHeight(600)
                            .setIntent(bubbleIntent)
                            .setAutoExpandBubble(true)
                            .setSuppressNotification(true)
                            .setIcon(icon)
                            .build()
            )
            .addPerson(person)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setWhen(message.date)
            .setStyle(style)
            .setShortcutInfo(
                    new ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(context, message.conversationId + "")
                            .setActivity(new ComponentName(context, ChatActivity.class))
                            .setCategories(new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)))
                            .setIcon(icon)
                            .setPerson(person)
                            .setRank(0)
                            .setShortLabel(person.getName())
                            .setIntent(intent)
                            .build()
            )
            .build();


    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(message.id + "," + message.type,
            message.id, notification);
```

Manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name=".screens.chat.ChatActivity"
        android:allowEmbedded="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="true"
        tools:targetApi="n" />
```

Gradle

```
targetSDKVersion 30
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02'
```

Comment: In Android 11 The BubbleMetadata.Builder() constructor with no parameters is deprecated.Use either of the two new constructors BubbleMetadata.Builder(PendingIntent, Icon) or BubbleMetadata.Builder(String).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing that I missed was adding `.setLongLived(true)` for the `ShortcutInfoCompat`. It solves the problem.

I learned that it best to manage the `ShortcutInfo` on the app level since you can have at most 5 at a time, so there is no harm caching those in memory, it includes the `Person` object as well.

Also, you should add [LocusId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/LocusId) for the `NotificationCompat`, this id is shared among shortcuts, notifications, and views. To add it to the views you need to put in some extra work, as described in [ContentCaptureManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/contentcapture/ContentCaptureManager)